# How to use scipy signal for MIMO systems

Tags: scipy, signal-processing

I am looking for a way to simulate the output of a signal for various input signals. To be more precise, I have a system defined by its transfer function H that takes one input and has one output. I generated several signals (stored in a numpy array). What I would like to do, is get the response of the system, to each input signal whithout using a for loop. Is there a way to proceed? Below is the code I wrote so far.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

nbr_inputs = 5
t_in = np.arange(0,10,0.2)
dim = (nbr_inputs, len(t_in))

x = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(0,2e-3, dim), axis=1)
H = signal.TransferFunction([1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 1])
t_out, y, _ = signal.lsim(H, x[0], t_in) # here, I would just like to simply write x
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a MIMO system, it is a SISO system but you have multiple inputs.

You can create a MIMO system and apply your inputs all at once which will be computed channel by channel but simultaneously. Moreover, you can't use `scipy.signal.lsim` for MIMO systems yet. You can use other options such as `python-control` (if you have `slycot` extension otherwise again no MIMO) or  `harold` if you have Python 3.6 or greater (disclaimer: I'm the author).

```
import numpy as np
from harold import *
import matplotlib.pyplot
nbr_inputs = 5
t_in = np.arange(0,10,0.2)
dim = (nbr_inputs, len(t_in))

x = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(0,2e-3, dim), axis=1)

# Forming a 1x5 system, common denominator will be completed automatically
H = Transfer([[[1, 3, 3]]*nbr_inputs], [1, 2, 1])
```

The keyword `per_channel=True` applies first input to first channel, second input to second and so on. Otherwise combined response is returned. You can check the shapes by playing around with it to see what I mean.

```
# Notice it is x.T below -> input shape = <num samples>, <num inputs>
y, t = simulate_linear_system(H, x.T, t_in, per_channel=True)

plt.plot(t, y)
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally opted for the python-control since I'm using python 2.7. I however discovered that I was limited to 49 inputs. Is there a way to go arround this limitation?

Comment: @s_o_king No idea about that limit. Are you maybe running out of memory or something?